# Syntax error while appending string separated by commas in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have following query

```
SELECT diamondsList.*, dealers.* FROM diamondsList JOIN dealers ON diamondsList.dealerId = dealers.id WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat AND clarity IN (SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL) AND color IN (J,H,D,E,F,G,I) AND diamondsType IN (BR,HS,CUS,RAD,AS,PRIN,OV,PS,MQ,EM)
```

But I AM getting error

```
   {"error":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FL) AND color IN (J,H,D,E,F,G,I) AND diamondsType IN (BR,HS,CUS,RAD,AS,PRIN,OV,P' at line 1"}
```

What syntax error is there near 'FL?

Not that query upto

```
SELECT diamondsList.*, dealers.* FROM diamondsList JOIN dealers ON diamondsList.dealerId = dealers.id WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat
```

works perfectly.

Comment: The specific error is the use of a reserved word (IF). You probably wanted a string ('IF'). Incidentally, if 'IF' really was to be used as a column identifier in this context then you'd either have to prepend it with a table identifier (my_table.if) or wrap it in backticks (\`IF\`). But a better idea would be to avoid reserved words altogether! Note that the error is almost always to be found immediately to the left of the portion of text quoted in the error message.

Comment: Error is because you use MySQL key words like IF and AS in the IN()..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I have a string "SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL" How would i do this*

If you have values in CSV format, then you need [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to search in it.

Change:

```
clarity IN (SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL)
```

To:

```
find_in_set( clarity, 'SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL' )
```

And it seems, the same issue persists in some other parts of your query.
You need to apply the same `FIND_IN_SET` on those parts.

Answer (score 2):

Your string values must be in quotes:

```
IN (SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL)
```

should be

```
IN ('SI2','VS1','SI1','VS2','VVS2','VVS1','IF','FL')
```

This applies to all of the strings in your query (i.e. check your other IN() statements)

Comment: I have a string "SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL" How would i do this

Comment: See @Ravinder's answer. It is a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Umer PLease use the below query

```
SELECT diamondsList.*, dealers.* FROM diamondsList 
  JOIN dealers ON diamondsList.dealerId = dealers.id 
WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice 
  AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat 
  AND clarity IN ("SI2","VS1","SI1","VS2","VVS2","VVS1","IF","FL") 
  AND color IN ("J","H","D","E","F","G","I") 
  AND diamondsType IN ("BR","HS","CUS","RAD","AS","PRIN","OV","PS","MQ","EM")
```

If "SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL" is a single string the you dont need to use IN() you can just use LIKE operator..

```
SELECT diamondsList.*, dealers.* FROM diamondsList 
  JOIN dealers ON diamondsList.dealerId = dealers.id 
WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice 
  AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat 
  AND clarity LIKE "SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL" 
  AND color IN ("J","H","D","E","F","G","I") 
  AND diamondsType IN ("BR","HS","CUS","RAD","AS","PRIN","OV","PS","MQ","EM")
```

What syntax error is there near 'FL?
Answer is before FL there IF and IF is a keyword in mySQL. so when you will user quotes the it will remove the error..

And if you have a string of "SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL" and you want to find it in individual elements then use following query.

```
SELECT diamondsList.*, dealers.* FROM diamondsList 
  JOIN dealers ON diamondsList.dealerId = dealers.id 
WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice 
  AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat 
  AND FIND_IN_SET(clarity,"SI2,VS1,SI1,VS2,VVS2,VVS1,IF,FL")  
  AND FIND_IN_SET(color,"J,H,D,E,F,G,I") 
  AND FIND_IN_SET(diamondsType,"BR,HS,CUS,RAD,AS,PRIN,OV,PS,MQ,EM")
```

Feel free to ask question if you still dont understand..