# Unable to set single quote in select in jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am  using in clause prepared statement

```
String id="1,2,3,4";

select * from abcd where id in (?)
```

As in setString `''` is appended around string so

I am replacing `,` by "`','`"

```
id=id.replaceAll(","," ',' ")
```

But when passing in prepared statement

```
prepStmt.setString (1,id);
```

instead of `'1','2','3','4'`

in query it is `'1\',\2',\'3`.....

Comment: You have to use a solution similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/22044688/767881

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from abcd where FIND_IN_SET(id ,?)
```

Try above code.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user1697114 great..!!
`Keep It Up!!`